# What does "one week's notice" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "one week's notice" mean in this context?

*Here's the context:*

> Termination of Assignment
>
> The legislation requires a THA to provide an assignment employee with at least **one week's notice** when an assignment scheduled to last longer than three months will be terminated early.
>
> If **one week's notice** is not given, the assignment employee must receive pay in lieu of notice, unless the assignment employee is offered at least one week's worth of reasonable work during the notice period.

My research shows that it might be a notice to be given in a week, but I'm not sure what does "notice" here exactly refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ten days'/ two weeks'/ three months' etc  notice :

a warning in advance that something is going to happen

*Notice* is also an official statement saying an agreement, job, etc., will end soon.